# ASP.NET MVC : check if referrer from same project and specified controller and action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, referrer, server-variables

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. I have an action which has static base64 of an image.

I want this action to render the correct image only if it is called from `myproject/allowedController/allowedAction` else show a different image.

I also want to restrict if someone is loggedin at my website and open the image url directly, but referrer is always returned as empty.

I tried with this code:

```
string host = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToString().Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "").ToLower();   
//string host = Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToString().Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "").ToLower();

 string localPath = Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath.ToString().ToLower();

 if (host != "www.mydomain.com")
 {
       throw new Exception("unauthorized request code 1");
 }

 if (!(localPath.StartsWith("/allowedController/allowedAction")))
 {
        throw new Exception("unauthorized request code2");
 }
```

Host is always throwing an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: "but referrer is always coming empty I tried as below" - modern web-browsers won't send the `Referer` header unless it's over TLS - and many privacy-boosting extensions also block sending the header.

Comment: Anyway, **You should not restrict access to content based on the `Referer` header.**. You'll end up breaking your website for legitimate users - and users that want to hotlink your content know how to get around those filters anyway.

Comment: I want to show different image if requested from mydomain while different one if request from anywhere else

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: any other approach should I implement to achieve above requirement